# Pandas impute Null with average of previous and next value in the row

Tags: python, pandas, null, imputation

I have a dataframe with several Nulls scattered here and there. I want to impute the value of the Nulls with the average of previous and next value in the same row, but only for the nulls which have a numeric value on their left and right columns.

In the below example, I would like to impute only the Nan in the *2nd row* and column *c2*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5,np.nan,np.nan,8], [9,np.nan,11,np.nan]], columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'])
```

**Out**

```
   c1   c2    c3   c4
0   1  2.0   3.0  4.0
1   5  NaN   NaN  8.0
2   9  NaN  11.0  NaN
```

Will becomes

```
   c1   c2    c3   c4
0   1  2.0   3.0  4.0
1   5  NaN   NaN  8.0
2   9  10  11.0  NaN   <-- value 10 replaces Nan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with parameters `axis=1` for procesing per rows, `limit_area='inside'` for processing `NaN`s values surrounded by valid values and `limit=1` for filled maximum `1`.

There is also default parameter `limit_direction='forward'`, so if more values of `NaN`s only first is replaced. You can find it by another `interpolate` with `limit_direction='backward'` and testing missing values used for replace after by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
mask = df.interpolate(axis=1, limit_area='inside', limit=1, limit_direction='backward').isna()
df1 = df.interpolate(axis=1, limit_area='inside', limit=1).mask(mask)
print (df1)
    c1    c2    c3   c4
0  1.0   2.0   3.0  4.0
1  5.0   NaN   NaN  8.0
2  9.0  10.0  11.0  NaN
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.interpolate(axis=1, limit_area='inside', limit=1))
    c1    c2    c3   c4
0  1.0   2.0   3.0  4.0
1  5.0   6.0   NaN  8.0
2  9.0  10.0  11.0  NaN

print (df.interpolate(axis=1, limit_area='inside', limit=1, limit_direction='backward'))
    c1    c2    c3   c4
0  1.0   2.0   3.0  4.0
1  5.0   NaN   7.0  8.0
2  9.0  10.0  11.0  NaN
```

Similar idea is use back filling with `limit=1` for test missing values:

```
mask = df.bfill(axis=1, limit=1).isna()
df1 = df.interpolate(axis=1, limit_area='inside', limit=1).mask(mask)
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.bfill(axis=1, limit=1))
    c1    c2    c3   c4
0  1.0   2.0   3.0  4.0
1  5.0   NaN   8.0  8.0
2  9.0  11.0  11.0  NaN
```

Comment: Wow - Never used either of the functions. Can I specify my custom function instead of avg?

Comment: @Ali - It is more complicated, because `interpolate` use some default methods

Comment: can we specify the columns where the interpolation should work and leave the rest. For example, can I specify to only consider columns c1,c2 and c3 but not c4. I know one way is to drop the column and may be introduce it later on but looking for a more efficient solution.